# Autocomplete textbox in asp.net mvc4 using ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to fetch company name in `textbox` as autocomplete. When I run my project, Ajax will call the success function, and the record is also fetched correctly, but there are no `autocomplete` suggestions in the `textbox`.

My view is:

```
    $("#idcompanyname").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {

            var customer = new Array();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '@Url.Action("Companymap", "admin")',
                data: "{'term':'" + document.getElementById('idcompanyname').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data)

                    response($.map(data, function (v, i) {
                        var text = v.vcCompanyName;
                        alet(text)
                        if (text && (!request.term || matcher.test(text))) {
                            return {
                                label: v.vcCompanyName,
                                value: v.kCompanyId
                            };
                        }
                    }));
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("No Match");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Here is Method on controller:

```
       var query = db.tbaccounts.Where(t => t.vcCompanyName.ToLower()
                                           .StartsWith(term)).ToList();
       List<string> lst = new List<string>();
       foreach (var item in query)
       {
           lst.Add(item.vcCompanyName);
       }
       return Json(lst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Here is the referred Javascript:

```
<script src="~/script/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/script/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: pl add jquery ui css file

Answer (score -1):

Please try removing

`~/script/jquery-2.0.3.js`

from the script references in your application, and that should work for you....